# How to pass multiple parameters to `\clist_map_function`?

Tags: expl3, l3regex

I try to use a `clist` for the parameters for a function. One parameter, however, can contain also additional optional parameters for the function.

How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:nnN { nx }

\seq_new:N \l__ghs_tmpA_seq
\seq_new:N \l__ghs_tmpB_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\HPsatz}{mO{}O{}}{
    \regex_extract_all:nxN {([HP+\d]*)} {#1} \l__ghs_tmpA_seq
    \regex_extract_all:nxN {\[(.*)\]} {#1} \l__ghs_tmpB_seq
%   \seq_use:Nn \l__ghs_tmpB_seq {,}
    #1:~
    \str_case_e:nnF { \seq_item:Nn \l__ghs_tmpA_seq { 1 } } {
        { H123 }{ First~sentence. }
        { H124 }{ Second~sentence. }
        { H125 }{ Third\seq_item:Nn \l__ghs_tmpB_seq { 1 }~sentence. }             
    }
    {not found}
    \\
}


\newcommand {\GHStext}[1]
{
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \HPsatz
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \GHStext{H123, H125[~best][really]}
    
\end{document}
```

Is the `regex` the cleanest way to go? Why does it keep putting the `[` and `]` in the match of the regex although it is outside of the brakets?

Comment: Your function would need to parse for the existence of the optional parameter.

Comment: IIRC, `\regex_extract_all` store as element 1 the entire match, and as 1+n the match of group n, so `\seq_item:Nn \l__ghs_tmpB_seq { 2 }` should give your item (but I didn't consult the documentation for this comment, so take it with a grain of salt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex based approach, but you need nothing as fancy as `\regex_extract:nnN`. You can just brace whatever comes before a `[` (if any).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\HPsatz}{mO{}O{}}
  {
    #1:~
    \str_case_e:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { H123 }{ First~sentence. }
        { H124 }{ Second~sentence. }
        { H125 }{ Third~sentence#2#3. }             
      }
      {not found}
    \par
  }


\NewDocumentCommand{\GHStext}{m}
  {
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__ghs_split:n
  }

\tl_new:N \l__ghs_tmp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ghs_split:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__ghs_tmp_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { ([^\[]*) } { \{\1\} } \l__ghs_tmp_tl
    \exp_last_unbraced:NV \HPsatz \l__ghs_tmp_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\GHStext{H123, H125[~best][really]}
    
\end{document}
```

I just used somehow the optional arguments.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the very short and clean solution. I will try to understand it fully to learn from it.

Comment: What does `\regex_replace_once:nnN` do in this case exactly? It replaces everything except `[` with the text found? I would expect at least the `[` to be gone. However, `\l__ghs_tmp_tl`looks the same before and after. But the number of items and tokens in it have somehow changed in a way I am not able to comprehend. Also I do not understand how the `exp_last_unbraced:NV` works in this case. According to the docu it expands the tl and puts it after the function name. Thus calling the function with the arguments. But why is the `regex_replace_once:nnN` necessary before?

Comment: I think I get it more now: the `\regex_replace_once:nnN` replaces everything before the first `[` with the same but inside `{` and `}`. The rest is left unchanged. So you basicly formatted `#1` as a proper argument with the mandatory argument in `{}` and leaving the optional arguments in `[]` and then use the `\exp_last_unbraced:NV` to put that (basicly a normal function call) in the input stream thus calling the function correctly. Right?

Comment: @mrCarnivore Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky bit is converting `H125[ best]` to `{H125}[ best]` so it is the right argument form for your command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\HPsatz}{mO{}O{}}{
    #1:~
    \str_case_e:nnF { #1 } {
        { H123 }{ First~sentence. }
        { H124 }{ Second~sentence. }
        { H125 }{ Third#2~sentence. }             
    }
    {not found}
    \par
}

\cs_new:Npn\HP_grab:w#1[#2]#3\scan_stop:{\HPsatz{#1}[#2]}

\seq_new:N \l__ghs_seq_numbers
\newcommand {\GHStext}[1]
{
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {\HP_grab:w##1[]\scan_stop:}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \GHStext{H123, H125[~best]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that is really crazy code. Thanks for the help. Do you think `regex` would be cleaner? I have updated my code in the question.

Comment: @mrCarnivore `regex` is great for quick solutions in your own document, but it's slow. I'd not use it for package code; either go with the low level function provided here, or implement something similar yet more stable.

Comment: @mrCarnivore a cleaner approach would be not to mix levels like this and map expl3 frunctions over the list not document commands. expl3 functions never have optional arguments and if you had a clist that always has `{}{}` so `{H123}{}, {H125}{ best}`  then maping an expl3 `\foo:nn` function would't require any of the trick parsing for optional []

Comment: Good point. Maybe the regex approach is better then. Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: @mrCarnivore regex is massively expensive processing, if your user interface requires that to implement it's a sign that there are issues with the desired interface

Comment: You are right. I was not able to come up with a better solution, though... My problem is I want to select text from a huge set of numbered sentences. Also for a small number of sentences I want to provide a possibility to extend the selected sentence in predefined positions (different for each sentence).

Comment: How expensive is regex in LaTeX, though? I am only familiar with the implementation in Python which is crazy fast.

Comment: @mrCarnivore the python one is implemented in C the latex one is implemented as tex macros, the delimited argument I used is one expansion step the regex alternative is probably a thousand or two, add `\tracingall`  and look at the log/

Comment: Maybe I like the regex solution better because I understand it... I will try to understand your solution also!

Comment: @mrCarnivore I didn't explicitly benchmark this, but I'd expect your regex to take around 2000 times longer than the simple one-step delimited argument expansion shown here. Also, I'd suggest to change order of things: put the optional argument in front instead of at the end of the key, parsing is much easier that way.

Answer (score 2):

The following implements a reasonable stable parsing for your input, provided that the optional part is put in front, instead of trailing to the key. It allows reasonably flexible input, but doesn't cope with nested `[]` inside the optional argument without additional braces (so `[a[b]c]` would read `a[b` as the optional argument, `[{a[b]c}]` would work and read `a[b]c`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \__ghs_oarg:Nn #1#2
  { \use:e { \exp_not:N #1 \__ghs_oarg_search:n {#2} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__ghs_oarg_search:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF {#1} [
      { \if_false: { \fi: \__ghs_oarg_collect:w #1 } }
      { {} { \exp_not:n {#1} } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__ghs_oarg_collect:w [#1]
  {
    { \exp_not:n {#1} }
    \exp_after:wN \__ghs_oarg_collect_aux:n
      \exp_after:wN { \if_false: } \fi:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__ghs_oarg_collect_aux:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_single:nTF {#1}
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} }
      { { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_all:nnN { nx }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \GHStext { m }
  { \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__ghs_hpsatz_wrapper:n }
\cs_new:Npn \__ghs_hpsatz_wrapper:n #1
  { \__ghs_oarg:Nn \__ghs_hpsatz:nn {#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\HPsatz}{mO{}}
  { \__ghs_hpsatz:nn {#2} {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \__ghs_hpsatz:nn #1#2
  {
    #2:~
    \str_case_e:nnF {#2} {
        { H123 }{ First~sentence. }
        { H124 }{ Second~sentence. }
        { H125 }{ Third#1~sentence. }             
    }
    {not~ found}
    \\
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \GHStext
      {
        H123,
        [~test1]H125,
        [~test2] H125,
        [~test3]{H125},
        [~test4] {H125}
      }
    
\end{document}
```